# Automount using UUID and fstab does not mount automatically after reboot

Tags: hard-drive, mount, automount

I have a Debian 10 in which I have one external ntfs drive.
I have modified my `/etc/fstab` file to allow auto mounting of the drive liek the following:

```sh
UUID="45DA303C05C96FEF"     /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF   ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,sync     0   1
```

However, when I reboot, I do not have the drive automatically mounted. If I make a `mount` command, I do not have the line with my drive in the output.

I need to click on the drive in Dolphin to get it mounted and after this, if I make the `mount` command, I get one of the lines as follows:

```sh
UUID="45DA303C05C96FEF"     /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF   ntfs    /dev/sdb1 on /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Instead, if I mount the drive using the device instead of the UUID, in the fstab file, it gets automounted without any problem. That means, if I put the following line in the fstab file:

```sh
/dev/sdb1   /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF   ntfs    rw,suid,dev,exec,auto,user,sync     0   1
```

Anyone can tell me how I can automatically mount the drive using the UUID instead of the device path?

Comment: Try without the double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @TomYan for the answer.

To allow the automount to work with UUID, you must use the UUID without the double quotes. Indeed it works.
The fstab entry shall be :

```sh
UUID=45DA303C05C96FEF     /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF   ntfs    /dev/sdb1 on /media/patou/45DA303C05C96FEF type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096,uhelper=udisks2)
```

not with `UUID="45DA303C05C96FEF"`